# Polynomials having the generating function $\exp(x(e^{t_1}+e^{t_2}-2))$

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

The generating function of the Touchard polynomials $T_n(x)$ is given by $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{T_n(x)}{n!}t^n = \exp(x(e^t-1)).$$
Is there a known set of polynomials having a generating function $$\exp(x(e^{t_1}+e^{t_2}-2))?$$
More general,
$$\exp(x(\sum_{n=1}^d (e^{t_n}-1)))?$$

Comment: I wonder if it is useful to note that if your original generating function is $g(x,t)=e^{x(e^t-1)}$ then your more general one is $g(x,t_1)g(x,t_2)\cdots g(x,t_n)$?

Comment: Also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540232/product-of-generating-functions) may be of interest. Generally, googling "product of generating functions" seems to be fruitful.

Comment: $d$-fold products of the $T_n$, i.e.
$$ \exp\left(x\left(\sum_{n=1}^d \left(e^{t_n}-1\right)\right)\right) = \sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots n_d=0}^\infty T_{n_1}(x) \ldots T_{n_d}(x) \frac{t_1^{n_1} \ldots t_d^{n_d}}{n_1! \ldots n_d!} $$

Comment: Thank you so much sir Robert Israel and MPW. Very much appreciated.